# How to screen share with Ubuntu 16.04 from Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: mac, vnc

I am unable to view and control my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop using screen sharing on a Mac desktop running OS X 10.11.6.  I've read on other forums about running dconf editor on the Ubuntu machine and turning off encryption for authentication; this worked for me under Ubuntu 14.04 but it is not working on 16.04.  The Mac sees the Ubuntu VNC server but when I enter the password for screen sharing the wheel spins for a while and then fails.  Can anyone suggest a current fix for this problem?

Comment: VPN? Did you mean VNC?

Comment: Duh!  Yes, I meant VNC, not VPN...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptoms (with the same OS versions), and by connecting a monitor to my Ubuntu machine found that Screen Sharing had defaulted to requiring confirmation for each access to the machine. Changing that setting enabled me to connect. I'm guessing that you've ruled this out already, but thought I'd suggest it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link: there is more settings that need to be set in dconf-editor 'vnc' security mode and you might want to set a password. This offers detailed step-by-step instructions.http://www.japanmobiletech.com/2015/02/screen-sharing-between-mac-os-x-1010.html.  While the directions are for an earlier version of ubuntu, they still apply to 16.04 which is what I am using.